# Meanings inferred from “Das ist alles”

Tags: translation, meaning-in-context

While the phrase *das ist alles* literally means *that is all*, are there any other meanings that can be taken from it?

For example, when my kids ask if there is any more apple juice, is *Nein, das ist alles* (while holding up the empty bottle) an appropriate way to say that there is *no more*?  Or is there a better way to do that?

Comment: Is it possible that they say "Das ist alle"? Because that would mean "It is empty"

Comment: @Emanuel: They ask if there is more juice, then the OP says (wants to say) _Das ist alles_.

Comment: @chirlu... oh I misread but then I don't understand the question. Why should it mean "no more"? Is it the case in English?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Das ist alles.

is an appropriate answer in my opinion. It is a short form of

> Das war alles, was noch da war.

The expression can also used in other situations:

> *(In a store)*
>   Shop assistant: "Kann ich sonst noch etwas für Sie tun?"
>   Customer: "Nein danke! Das ist alles."

or

> He: "Warum willst du mich verlassen?"
>   She: "Ich liebe dich nicht mehr. Das ist alles."

Comment: Is it the German equivalent of "that's it"? Especially in your last example.

Comment: @Gigili yes, I guess so.

Comment: I have to disagree with the first statement. To me "Das ist alles" clearly implies the fact that there is some. You "point" to this "some" by saying "das". It is technically not a demonstrative pronoun, yet it works like it. "Das war alles." is ok since it is in past but in present you would point to void while indicating that there is still something. "Der (Apfelsaft) ist alle" or simply "Alle!" or "Leider alle!" are more common in the situation with the juice, I'd say

Answer (score 4):

The colloquial usage of ***"alle"*** (note the missing 's') in the following sentence

> *"Der Apfelsaft ist alle"*

is etymological related to *"alles"*, *"all"* in the meaning of *the whole* but in this context means that *all* is used up.